# Spring boot (mysql with jpa ): No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Tags: java, spring, jpa, exception, spring-boot

Started building a(*first*) spring boot application and this is my spring boot main class ([Full code on github](https://github.com/sureshatta/stackOverflowExamples/tree/master/SpringBoot/MySQL))

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I am keep getting the below error. What I am missing to add? Why I need to add a bean  bean named 'entityManagerFactory' ?? and is it necessary even after using spring boot ??

My repo looks like this if that matter

```
public interface RegistrationRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
     User findByEmail(String email); 
}
```

> .   ____          _            __ _ _
>   /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
>   ( ( )_** | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \
>   \/*  )| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
>    '  |____| .|*| |*|*| |*__, | / / / /
>   =========|_|==============|___/=/*/*/_/
>   :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)
>
> 2017-09-13 12:48:38.808  INFO 15361 --- [           main] com.rightlink.RightLinkApplication       : Starting RightLinkApplication on Admins-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 15361 (/Users/sureshatta/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE/RightLink/target/classes started by sureshatta in /Users/sureshatta/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.0.RELEASE/RightLink)
>   2017-09-13 12:48:38.811  INFO 15361 --- [           main] com.rightlink.RightLinkApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
>   2017-09-13 12:48:38.865  INFO 15361 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@120d6fe6: startup date [Wed Sep 13 12:48:38 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   2017-09-13 12:48:40.380  INFO 15361 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8181 (http)
>   2017-09-13 12:48:40.402  INFO 15361 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
>   2017-09-13 12:48:40.403  INFO 15361 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
>   2017-09-13 12:48:40.566  INFO 15361 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
>   2017-09-13 12:48:40.567  INFO 15361 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1705 ms
>   2017-09-13 12:48:40.743  INFO 15361 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
>   2017-09-13 12:48:40.752  INFO 15361 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
>   2017-09-13 12:48:40.753  INFO 15361 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
>   2017-09-13 12:48:40.753  INFO 15361 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
>   2017-09-13 12:48:40.753  INFO 15361 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
>   2017-09-13 12:48:40.844  WARN 15361 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'registerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'regServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'regService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'registrationRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'registrationRepo': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#43c67247' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#43c67247': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
>   2017-09-13 12:48:40.849  INFO 15361 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
>   2017-09-13 12:48:40.903  INFO 15361 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2017-09-13 12:48:40.975 ERROR 15361 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
>
> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field registrationRepo in com.rightlink.services.RegistrationService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=8181
```

Tried adding `@Repository` annotation for repo, and also added `@enableJpaRepositories` annotation in main class. Nothing helps.

Comment: Spring(more precisely JPA) needs to know where your entityManagerFactory is and then use it for managing entity manager. Refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html

Comment: @spiritwalker But I do not need a custom data source, would like to go with default one.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ are you sure that's the only log message you have?

Comment: @MangEngkus  I belive so. Updated with complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 4):

Issue is not with boot version directly and issues are with staled hibernate jars. Since I added JPA support to the project, boot internally using(??) Hibernate as a JPA implementation and trying to use (??) those jars. Since my local repo have have corrupted `hibernate-entity-* jars`, this weird error happening.

Their [comment in the code](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/) confirming that they use hibernate internally.

```
 <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Removed the complete hibernate folder from my maven local repo and nowit seems ok.

Comment: The application that you've shared works for me. Both with `1.3.1.RELEASE` and `1.5.6.RELEASE`. I believe one jar may have been corrupted when you downloaded 1.5.6 for the first time. Switch to that and run `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` to remove the corrupted jar.

Comment: Yeap I also have a spring-boot application with `1.5.6.RELEASE` and it works out of the box with the same setup as yours.